# Z3: wrong result when proving equivalence of two formulas. Z3 error?

Tags: python, z3

I want to prove the equivalence of two formulas 'f' and 'g' with Z3 python. 
In the below code, basically 'g' is 'f' with some random code added. I ignored all the random code in 'g' with Exists qualifier, so 'f' and 'g' are actually equivalent.

```
MI = BitVecSort(32)
MV = BitVecSort(8)
Mem = Array('Mem', MI, MV)

def equivalence(F, G):
    s = Solver()
    s.add(Not(F == G))
    if s.check() == unsat:
        print "Equivalence"
    else:
        print "Inequivalence"

def Select2(M, I): 
    return Concat(Select(M, I+1), Select(M, I))

x, y = BitVecs('x y', 32)

g = True
t = BitVec('t', 32)
g = And(g, t == y)
t2 = BitVec('t2', 16)
g = And(g, t2 == Select2(Mem, t))
t3 = BitVec('t3', 32)
g = And(g, t3 == (t + 2))
y1 = BitVec('y1', 32)
g = And(g, y1 == t)
x1 = BitVec('x1', 32)
g = And(g, x1 == 0)

f = True
x1 = BitVec('x1', 32)
f = And(f, x1 == 0)

equivalence(Exists([t3, t2, t, y, y1, x], g), f)
```

However, this script returns 'Inequivalence" rather than expected "Equivalence". Actually, looking more closely, s.check() in Equivalence returns "Unknown".

I expected Z3 to solve this trivial problem easily, but it seems Z3 is doing something wrong here. Any idea?

Lots of thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `unknown` because of the quantifier. You can get the expected answer by applying quantifier elimination. We can create a solver that uses `qe` and a `smt` solver. We just have to replace

```
   s = Solver()
```

with

```
   s = Then('qe', 'smt').solver()
```

`Then` is a combinator, it builds a tactic that applies `qe` (quantifier elimination) and then invokes a general purpose SMT solver `smt`. The method `.solver()` converts the tactic into a solver.

We can test it [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/p1pb).

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much, Leo! However, I tried this solution with a bit more complicated formulas, and it took forever to finish (so I had to kill the process after 15mins). I guess the culprit is the quantifier elimination process (?). Is there any way to speed up this solution?

Comment: Yes, qe is probably the bottleneck.

Comment: I tried with more cases, and it seems sometimes s=Solver() works (very fast), and sometimes only s = Then('qe', 'smt') works. So it seems we dont always need 'qe'? Why, and how can we know in advance which one works better?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no easy answer :(

Comment: Solver() also has support for quantifiers. It uses the techniques described at http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/files/ufbv_journal.pdf.

Comment: I really have a big problem with this. It seems there is no way to know in advance which one (s = Solver(), or s = Then('qe', 'smt').solver() will work for my constraint. For now, if one cannot solve the query, I kill the process and switch to the other one. But this cannot be done automatically. Leo, do you have any suggestion for this dilemma, please? Thanks so much!

Comment: Leo, I assume that there is absolutely no way to know in advance which of [s=Solver(); s = Then('qe', 'smt').solver] is better to handle Existent qualifier formula. However, given a formula, is there any quick/simple/easy heuristic method to tell me which solver might be 'better' than the other, so I run the 'better' one first to improve the performance? Thanks.